# Uniform convergence of Taylor remainder term

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi_\theta(t)$ be a $C^2$ function for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $\theta \in \Theta$ (i.e. we have a function for each $\theta$) with $\phi_\theta(0) = 1$, $\phi_\theta'(0) = 0$ and $\phi_\theta''(0) = -1$. Consider a first-order Taylor expansion, such that for each $t$ and $\theta$, we have some $\xi_\theta(t)$ between $0$ and $t$ so that 
$$
\phi_\theta(t) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\phi''(\xi_\theta(t)) t^2 .
$$

Let now $t_0$ be given and define for each $n$: $t_n = \frac{t_0}{\sqrt{n}}$. Does

$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} |1 + \phi_\theta''(\xi(t_n)) | \to 0 
$$

as $n \to \infty$? The claim is obviously true for each $\theta$ individually, since $t_n \to 0$ and thus $\xi_\theta(t_n)$ goes to zero and by continuity of $\phi_\theta''$, $\phi_\theta''(\xi(t_n)) \to -1$.

How can we say anything uniformly? Do we need further assumptions? I'm willing to assume perhaps that $\phi_\theta$ is $C^3$ if that is helpful.